# What does Try<String> mean in Groovy

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

Iam implementing codenarc static code analysis to the code and came across `Try<String>` return type for a method. I have the following questions.

1. What does `Try<String>` mean?
2. When I even Annotate the class with `@TypeChecked` it still cannot diffrentiate between String and Try. Is the Ide considering them the same since the data Type is same(String)? or is there an internal mechanism in Groovy which converts it to `.toString` such that the return type looks the same.

These two are not the same since it failed with the following error :-

```
"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Success{value=merchant}' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.typesafely.util.Try'\n\tat flasher.<Classname>.<MethodName>(<ClassName>.groovy:158) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Could you tell us what method, on which class, is returning `Try<String>`?

Comment: Could you show us your code that is generating the exception above?

Comment: In my opinion @Emmanuel has answered your question, can you please accept the answer if that is your understanding too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Try<T>` is a Scala API which can be used by code which has the potential to throw an exception, to return an object every time; a `Try<T>` instance. This `Try<T>` instance wraps either:

1. A value containing the result, in the case of a successful computation.
2. An exception, in the case of an unsuccessful result.

Here's a brief example:

```
@Grab('com.lambdista:try:0.3.1')

import com.lambdista.util.Try
import com.lambdista.util.FailableSupplier

Try<BigDecimal> divideBy(BigDecimal dividend, BigDecimal denominator) {
    Try.apply({ dividend / denominator } as FailableSupplier)
}

def a = divideBy(4, 2)
assert a.success
assert a.value == 2

def b = divideBy(4, 0)
assert b.failure
assert b.failed().toString() == 'Success{value=java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero}'
```

The example above demonstrates that code which could throw an exception, such as an `ArithmeticException`, when executed with `Try.apply()` the exception is instead caught and wrapped in an instance of `Try.Failure<T>`.

`Try<String>` is not the same as `String`. However, `Try.Success<T>` implements `toString()` in a way that produces the output you're seeing in the log: `'Success{value=merchant}'`

Comment: try.get() will return the embedded response if the result is a Success, otherwise throw an exception. To get the String, just make sure you're in the success case, and get() the value.
https://github.com/lambdista/try/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lambdista/util/Try.java

Comment: Of course, there is probably another `Try<X>` class out there, and this isn't necessarially the scala one...

Comment: True. The one I described is the closest match I found based on the question's description. It's not even the one from Scala, but rather an re-implementation for Java 8.